# How do I mute/unmute all sound coming from Firefox via a shortcut command?

Tags: command-line, sound, firefox, shortcut-keys

My goal is to have a custom shortcut, which mutes/unmutes all sound coming from Firefox, toggling between the two states. I can't seem to find any info on how to achieve that.

Comment: maybe [this article](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/4frreh/is_there_any_way_to_mute_all_tabs_by_default/) will help.

Comment: @SirajusSalekin It definetly goes in the right direction. The Play/Pause add-on is bugged for me, it seems. I doesn't register the keys I actually pressed but rather some rubbish. So, there is no way to mute a certain application via command?

Comment: And http://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard