# how can I map altgr to _

Tags: keyboard, xmodmap

I would like to map AlgGr to `_`.

How can I do that?

I have tried: `keysym keycode 135 = _` in my xmodmap config

But it is not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change what keys on my keyboard do? (How can I create custom keyboard commands/shortcuts?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard)

Comment: I am not sure this is a duplicate. As written in the linked answered I have tried to use: `xmodmap -e "keycode 108 = underscore"` but it is not working

Comment: Should the `_` not be `underscore`? Please look at it again...

Comment: isn'it as I wrote in the comment?

Comment: sorry the problem is probably not due to the xmodmap command but to the startup option that I have. I need to investigate more