# Launch url from desktop with a combination of keys

Tags: shortcut-keys

Is it possible in Ubuntu launch a url from desktop with a combination of keys?

In my job, in Windows, I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd> to open a website where I have some tools. I would like to do the same here in my house where I only have Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a keyboard shortcut for the command

```
xdg-open https://some-website
```

See [How can I change what keys on my keyboard do? (How can I create custom keyboard commands/shortcuts?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard/) for how to create keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Thanks, Mr. Diesch !

I used the terminal command you provided (xdg-open <url>) 
and followed the steps in 
Default keyboard and shortcut settings (from within System Settings)

I had to reboot ubuntu for the changes to take effect
which is not well clarified there.

Thank you very much.

Comment: @ShirleyTemple reboots aren't necessary for creating desktop shortcuts, they take changes immediately. Likely what happened in your case is that the service that controls desktop settings had to be restarted, which is what you did by rebooting.