# Custom keyboard shortcut for issuing bash command in current terminal window

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys, terminator

I know I can create custom keyboard shortcuts in `System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts`. How would I create a custom keyboard shortcut for issuing a bash command in a terminal window I'm currently in? For instance, `echo "something"`.

I'm using terminator.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do that per se, but you could use `xdotool` to input a command then press Enter.

Comment: Although maybe what you're really looking for are Bash aliases and functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following answer is copied from [an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/254425/727448) to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard) question, and explains how to create a custom keyboard shortcut anywhere, which naturally also will work in a terminal. I'm posting the solution that worked well for me - please check out the linked question for other alternatives. All credit goes to the original author [Seth](https://askubuntu.com/users/44179/seth).

## xbindkeys..

```
sudo apt-get install xbindkeys
```

Xbindkeys is a very versatile program that lets you remap keys very easily.  It uses a config file, my default located in your home directory, to change key bindings into certain commands.

To create a default config file you use the command:

```
xbindkeys --defaults
```

Which prints the default config file.  So if you want to *create* the file containing the default values you would use:

```
xbindkeys --defaults > $HOME/.xbindkeysrc
```

Which prints the default values into a hidden file named `.xbindkeysrc` located in home (`~`).

Now to actually *change* the bindings of keys we first need to know what the name or keysym of those keys is.  `xbindkeys` allows us to use the `-k` handle to find the name of a key or key combination.  Run:

```
xbindkeys -k
```

And press a key or key combination.  Your output will look *something* similar to this (when pressing <kbd>space</kbd>):

```
"NoCommand"
m:0x10 + c:65
Mod2 + space
```

`"No Command"` tells us that currently no command is associated with the <kbd>Space</kbd> key.

```
m:0x10 + c:65
Mod2 + space
```

Is the name of the key/key combination.

## the config file..

Lets open up the config file you made earlier:

```
gedit .xbindkeysrc
```

Here is an excerpt from the default config file:

```
#
# A list of keys is in /usr/include/X11/keysym.h and in
# /usr/include/X11/keysymdef.h
# The XK_ is not needed.
#
# List of modifier:
#   Release, Control, Shift, Mod1 (Alt), Mod2 (NumLock),
#   Mod3 (CapsLock), Mod4, Mod5 (Scroll). 
#

# The release modifier is not a standard X modifier, but you can  
# use it if you want to catch release events instead of press events

# By defaults, xbindkeys does not pay attention with the modifiers
# NumLock, CapsLock and ScrollLock.
# Uncomment the lines above if you want to pay attention to them.

#keystate_numlock = enable
#keystate_capslock = enable
#keystate_scrolllock= enable

# Examples of commands:

"xbindkeys_show" 
 control+shift + q
```

Every line beginning with `#` is a comment and won't be read or run by `xbindkeys`.

So far the only line that isn't commented out is:

```
"xbindkeys_show" 
 control+shift + q
```

This excerpt shows the basic syntax of `xbindkeys` commands:

```
"Command to run (in quotes)"
key to associate with command (no quotes)
```

So as you can see:

```
"xbindkeys_show" 
 control+shift + q
```

Runs the command `xbindkeys_show` when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>.

## bind keys to commands..

Now lets try binding a few keys.  I recommend clearing the entire default file so that it's blank.  It contains preset key bindings you probably don't want.

Now lets say you want to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> to open your browser.  First you need to know what the name or *keysym* of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> is.  As mentioned earlier you can use `xbindkeys -k` to find the name of a key or keys, but there is an easier way.  For simple combinations like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> you can just use:

```
Control+b
```

A lot easier isn't it!

Now find the command for your favorite browser:

- For Firefox: `firefox`
- For Chromium: `chromium-browser`
- For Opera:  `opera`

Remember the syntax from earlier?  The `xbindkeys` command to launch Firefox (or your other favorite browser) when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> is:

```
"firefox"
Control+b
```

Now put that in your config file and save it.  Now you might notice your command doesn't work yet, that's because `xbindkeys` isn't running.  To start it just run `xbindkeys` from a terminal.  Your <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> should now start your browser!