# Skip GNOME Screenshot prompt and shutter sound

Tags: gnome, screenshot, gnome-screenshot

I was wondering if there is a way of skipping `gnome-screenshot` prompt when pressing <kbd>printscreen</kbd> in order to record the file directly to a folder and also skipping the annoying shutter sound.

Does anyone have an idea or alternative? I used to use Purrint for a long time under Windows and I'm missing it right now.

Thanks a lot for any clue, note, enlightenment, comment ;)

Comment: By default print button shouldn't show the prompt window, it should just take a screenshot of the whole screen with a shutter sound. Anyway I think I can help. I'm working on an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings -> keyboard -> custom shortcut. Add a new one, give it the name you want, and as a command write `gnome-screenshot` save it, then assign it the key you prefer. Note that if you try to assign the printscreen key, it will ask to reassign it because it's already use.

Comment: This only solves the prompt issue (which is fixed in Ubuntu 18.04), but not the flashing and shutter issue.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two possible ways to meet your goal.

### 1. Tweaking GNOME Screenshot

#### 1.1. Disabling prompt window

If you run the command

```
gnome-screenshot --interactive
```

the following window should pop up:
[image]
But if you run

```
gnome-screenshot
```

a shot of your whole screen should be saved to your *Pictures* folder without any delay (but there will be a mechanical camera shutter sound and the screen will blink once).

For convenience you may set a keyboard shortcut for this `gnome-screenshot` command (see [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard) for a detailed method of doing it). You may choose any keyboard combination which doesn't cause any conflict, for example <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Print</kbd>.

Once you set this keyboard shortcut, logout and login again. Now whenever you press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Print</kbd> a shot of the whole screen should be saved in your *Pictures* folder without showing any prompt.

#### 1.2. Disabling shutter sound

The camera shutter sound you hear when a screenshot is captured comes from the `camera-shutter.oga` file located at `/usr/share/sounds/freedesktop/stereo`. So removing/renaming this file should get rid of the shutter sound.

But I would **not** suggest anyone to do that. Among other things this `camera-shutter.oga` file will be restored after updating some associated package(s).

### 2. Using other applications

You may ditch `gnome-screenshot` completely and try some better alternative. I would suggest **Shutter**. You can install it from the Software Centre or by running

```
sudo apt-get install shutter
```

Once installed the following command will capture your whole screen and save it in your *Pictures* folder

```
shutter -f -e
```

The `-f` option makes sure the whole screen is captured and the `-e` option quits the programme once the screenshot is saved.

Like before you may set a keyboard shortcut for this `shutter -f -e` command, for example <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Print</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

mute "system sounds" in sound settings makes also gnome screenshot quiet, and it is not global, and from gnome-44 onwards also selecting a "none" for the sound theme has the same effect:
https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/6376

see also:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/735126/