# Remapping keys when keys are missing

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

This is what I got:
English laptop keyboard.
Using Swedish keymap. 
Latest Ubuntu.

Now I am a long term user of Autohotkey and was sad to see that Linux is missing the  equivalent. There are some bindings that I can live without but  some are really essential for me. I mainly  talking about "bigger than", "less than" and the "OR" sign. I usually remapp these to caps lock. To demonstrate, this is from my autohotkey script:

```
CapsLock::
    Send, <
Return

Shift & CapsLock::
    Send, >
Return

Alt & CapsLock::
    Send, |
Return
```

Easy enough so I began googling and found this helpful question explaining xbindkeys: [How can I change what keys on my keyboard do? (How can I create custom keyboard commands/shortcuts?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard)

The problem is that I really dont want to send any command, I just want to remap my keys and or write text. I cant use xautomation as Im missing those keys as Im using another layout.

Comment: Precisely those symbols are available via the key to the left of the Z key.