# How to use a remote presenter device to run custom programs?

Tags: usb, bluetooth, hardware-test

I have a remote presenter device that connects to my laptop using a usb dongle. It works perfectly for switching slides with Ubuntu's LibreOffice Impress (powerpoint). Is there a way to scan for these commands from my own c/c++ code and do what I like with them?

Comment: You could check if it's sending keyboard events with `xev -event keyboard`. If so, you could maybe find some helpful info at [How can I change what keys on my keyboard do?](https://askubuntu.com/q/254424/301745)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above comment, I realized that a presenter device sends the ascii codes same as some of the keys in the keyboard. So any keyboard event handling feature of available c++ libraries could be used to detect keyboard inputs. I used the one from opencv