# AutoKey question: How can I hold down a simulated keypress while holding down the key combination?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, autokey

My laptop's Escape key recently got broken so I temporarily mapped it to Super + X using AutoKey via `keyboard.fake_keypress("<escape>")`. However, I found that this doesn't hold down the Escape button but instead presses it once only. How do I script it to where as long as I'm holding down the key combination Super + X, the Escape button is also simulated held down. When I release, it also gets simulated released.

Comment: You better arrange this at a lower system level, using xbindkeys. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard

Comment: Should rather be xmodmap, the second answer in that link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with a high-level keyboard macro tool such as Autokey. You should remap your broken key using more low-level tools. `xmodmap` is installed by default, and allows to modify the keymap. For guidelines on how to proceed, see the excellent answer of Kevin Bowen, **Xev and xmodmap**, to the question [How can I change what keys on my keyboard do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard) here on [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).