# How to change text movement keyboard shortcuts

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I've looked through all the keyboard shortcuts in gnome-settings and dconf-editor and there were a lot of common shortcuts that I couldn't find. For example: the shortcuts for moving around text, highlighting text, copying and pasting, as well as some other stuff.

In particular, I would like to know how to remap <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>HOME</kbd> (which selects to the beginning of a line) to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+ to make it more like how it works on Mac OSX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/shell-keyboard-shortcuts.html.en lists common GNOME hotkeys, and https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html.en shows how to edit them.

Alternative methods are illustrated in [How can I change what keys on my keyboard do? (How can I create custom keyboard commands/shortcuts?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard/304834#304834)

Comment: I was looking for something more complicated than shell keyboard shortcuts, but I found my answer in the second link you provided with the package [AutoKey](https://askubuntu.com/a/304834/976234).