# Shortcuts with meta and two arrowkeys?

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu

Is it possible to use meta+arrowkey+arrowkey as a shortcut?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change what keys on my keyboard do? (How can I create custom keyboard commands/shortcuts?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keyboard shortcuts in Ubuntu are composed of 1 or more **modifier** keys, and one **regular** key. A regular key produces a character or is assigned an action when pressed on its own. These include most keys on your keyboard. A modifier key is a key that does nothing on its own, but that is pressed in combination with a regular key to change its behaviour. Modifier keys include <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd>.

A keyboard combination as  <kbd>meta</kbd>+<kbd>arrowkey</kbd>+<kbd>arrowkey</kbd> therefore is not possible because arrow keys are not modifier keys.

Examples of valid shortcut key combinations include: (1 modifier key): <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>, (2 modifier keys) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> or (3 modifier keys) <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>.