# How to bind caps lock to number pad 0?

Tags: keyboard

For the life of me, I just can not figure out how to bind caps lock to the number pad 0. By this I mean whenever I hit caps lock, it actually registers as number pad 0.

I want to do this to remap a hotkey in a game I play on Linux. On windows, I simply use autohotkey, on Linux no such things and all the tools I see on Linux like autokey and such I have no idea how to use and can not find any documentation that mentions how to do what I wanted.

Help, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could work (run in a terminal):

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = KP_0"
```

You can discover the keycode or keyname by using `xev`.

Numlock needs to be on. If it's off, the 0 key may be named `KP_insert`.

There's a great answer to a similar question [here (askubuntu)](https://askubuntu.com/a/257497) and it covers in some detail how you can use `xmodmap` and `xev` to achieve your goal.