# Chinese Pinyin keyboard layout in Ubuntu 20.04 is based on German layout

Tags: 20.04, keyboard-layout, ibus

I have recently upgraded Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. In the settings, my default input method is German.

I added the "Chinese Intelligent Pinyin" input method and it mostly worked as expected. But an issue remains: it still uses the German keyboard layout in Pinyin mode, i.e., when I press <kbd>y</kbd>, I get a <kbd>z</kbd> and vice versa.

How can I change the base layout of the Pinyin input method to English/Chinese?

Comment: check this trend it might help your problem https://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `/usr/share/ibus/component/libpinyin.xml` for editing. Then change

```
<layout>default</layout>
```

to

```
<layout>us</layout>
```

for the **libpinyin** engine.

Comment: Thanks, changing that mentioned file and logging out and logging in worked.

Comment: Great! This works perfectly. I wasted quite a lot of time on this due to 1) it has to be `us`, not anything else. EN-US seems very appealing, but won't work; 2) you have to logging out....