# How to toggle keybindings with a button

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, shortcut-keys

I want to create a custom keybinding where

```
i - up arrow
j - left arrow
k - down arrow
l - right arrow
```

I want to be able toggle this on/off by pressing say a key combination `shift+ctrl+i`.

How can I do this? I am able to create keybindings as according to the post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard)

But, if I create the key bindings with xkeybind, I need to restart the os to get it to work (using ubuntu 20.04)..

What if I use language regions to use different keyboards and change the keyboard settings for the other language keyboard? Can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, yes, it should work. If you buy a HHKB. [ ; ' / + Fn become arrow keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to do this by adding a another region keyboard (using english UK)

I used `xev` to get the keycode

```
KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x2e00001,
    root 0x5c5, subw 0x0, time 790965, (1386,793), root:(1394,865),
    state 0x10, keycode 44 (keysym 0x6a, j), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (6a) "j"
    XFilterEvent returns: False


KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0x5c5, subw 0x0, time 2590604, (72,-17), root:(80,55),
    state 0x2010, keycode 31 (keysym 0x69, i), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (69) "i"
    XFilterEvent returns: False


KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0x5c5, subw 0x0, time 2612248, (947,850), root:(955,922),
    state 0x2010, keycode 45 (keysym 0x6b, k), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (6b) "k"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3000001,
    root 0x5c5, subw 0x0, time 2612767, (947,850), root:(955,922),
    state 0x2010, keycode 46 (keysym 0x6c, l), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (6c) "l"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (6c) "l"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Then I used xmodmap to bind the keys

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 31 = i I KP_Up i" 
xmodmap -e "keycode 45 = k K KP_Down k" 
xmodmap -e "keycode 46 = l L KP_Right l" 
xmodmap -e "keycode 44 = j J KP_Left j"
```

If you want to reset the keybindings you can use
`setxkbmap -layout us`

To make this load everytime I open the computer, I've added it to `~/.bashrc`