# How to type/insert a long text when pressed shortcut

Tags: shortcut-keys

I need to find a unused shortcut in Ubuntu 18.04 and in Chrome and make it possible when I press that combination in Ubuntu it types or inserts a long text in a browser.

The background - I'm gonna take a certification exam which is browser based with a limited time. To save some time I'd like to press a shortcut and it types/inserts 5-10 bash aliases which I can use to save time. I will need to use this multiple times as this won't be a single terminal window.

Comment: You should make sure the exam allows that, as most that I know of do not. If you use it against the rules, you are cheating. By default, I don't think Chrome can do that. _Assuming the exam allows it_, consider a program like [AutoKey](https://github.com/autokey/autokey).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change what keys on my keyboard do? (How can I create custom keyboard commands/shortcuts?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard)

Comment: @cocomac this question, although the intens may be less noble, is specifically about how to paste a text snippet using a shortcut. Not to be found in the anwer you marked as duplicate. You may wish to retract your close vote or find another question about text snippets.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Xorg, the tools `xsel` and `xdotool` allow you to manipulate the clipboard and simulate pressing keystrokes. Following  code will retrieve a text file stored on your computer using `xsel`, and paste it at the location of the cursor using `xdotool`:

```
#!/bin/bash
CLIPITEM="/home/user13/snippet.txt"
SHORTCUT=Control+1
# Read clip item into clipboard
xsel -bi < "$CLIPITEM"
# paste snippet
xdotool keyup $SHORTCUT key Shift+Insert
```

You bind the script to a custom shortcut key.

Adapt the variables `CLIPITEM` and `SHORTCUT` to your situation. In the example, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> is used, and that is registered in `SHORTCUT`. In the script, that shortcut is released before simulating the shortcut key to paste content. Otherwise, it could interfere.

`xdotool`  and `xsel`  only work with the Xorg display driver. If you are on a desktop running Wayland, you will need to use dedicated tools. Currently, `ydotool` can simulate key presses, and the tools in `wl-clipboard` can interact with the clipboard.

Comment: I have created snippet.txt and aliases.sh. Executed aliases.sh it looked iike it inserted whatever I have had in clipboard at a time and after that shortcut did not work. I tend to believe that there's a missing bit here and it seems the whole aliases.sh should be bound to shortcut and this step is not explained.

Comment: You did not mention system information. This will work on Xorg only. For Wayland, look for equivalent tools

Comment: I'm not an ubuntu expert but I use 18.04. I read and it looks like 18.04 is xorg. I do not get how this will work. xdotool presses Shift + Insert once I press some Control+l. It will insert something from clipboard. Right? But who inserts correct stuff into clipboard? If let say I copy "the junk text" into clipboard. Then I press Control+l what will cause Shoft+Insert, but how my aliases appear in clipboard instead of "the junk text"? Whats the point of going Control+l instead of directly pressing Shift+Insert? Am I missing something?

Comment: When you press the shortcut key, the long text will be inserted in the clipboard and pasted. So this is where you type your long text by just hitting a shortcut key, which is, as far as I understood, what you are asking. The manual way indeed is not that much longer. You open the long text file, copy the text (Ctrl+c), move to the target application and paste (Shift+Insert or Ctrl+V.