# A .desktop icon for a bash script works, but

Tags: unity, scripts, icons

...the script is a wrapper script for an executable.  When the executable runs it shows up with the gray ? icon in the Unity bar, so I end up with two icons (the icon I want and the gray unknown icon).
How can I make it so I end up with only one icon (or two equal icons if need be).

Answer (score 0):

There's not much of a way to deal with such thing. Make another `.desktop` file for the program that has gray icon and store it in your `~/.local/share/applications`.

Information on how to do so can be found here: [Apply icons to bash scripts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60667/apply-icons-to-bash-scripts)