# How do I make Firefox run shell commands on application protocols?

Tags: firefox

Is there a way to make Firefox accept bash commands to handle an application protocol?

Currently, I am opening `irc://` links in XChat from Firefox via a shell script as described [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55779/open-irc-links-in-xchat-from-firefox-and-chromium/60325#60325). I would like to eliminate the script step and directly move on to opening the link in XChat.

Comment: Can you please give an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Well, I do not understand how the command itself will make a difference to the way to get Firefox to run it, but edited in the thing I command I want to run.

Answer (score 1):

You said you wanted to skip the shell script part. Basically you can execute the content of every shell skript like this:

```
bash -c "contents of shell script in one line"
```

In your case it would look like this:

```
bash -c "xchat --existing --url=\"%s\""
```

Since xchat is an executable independet of bash you should be able to start xchat directly:

```
/usr/bin/xchat --existing --url="%s"
```

Use `which xchat` to find out where `xchat` is installed on your system and replace the `/usr/bin` part if it is installed somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, I know the command itself (and it's `/usr/bin/xchat` by the way), but what I want to know is how to get Firefox to actually take commands instead just the path to directory.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this old post, it helped other people before:
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/how-to-register-irc-protocol-to-firefox-browser-283057/

P.S.: read the entire thread.

Comment: I already tried that suggested in a Ubuntu Forums thread. No luck.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.