# IRC client that automatically associates with IRC URI

Tags: software-recommendation, irc

I know there are workarounds for opening [IRC links with XChat](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55779/open-irc-links-in-xchat-from-firefox-and-chromium), but I'm looking for clients that does this automatically. I'm quite aware of Chatzilla as well, but it has a certain limitation I'm cannot to entertain. Preferably, those clients should meet the following criteria:

- DCC support
- GTK application, or anything that works in LXDE without pulling too many dependencies

Comment: It would help us if you can tell us what that limitation you cite is?

Comment: @it'sme The inability to automatically accept DCC requests.

Answer (score 1):

There is console version: [IRCII](http://www.eterna.com.au/ircii/news.html)

I do not know about DCC (to be honest), but I have used pidgin many times and had no issues with it: [Pidgin](http://pidgin.im/)

I have found this which seems to have support:[Smuxi](http://www.smuxi.org)

Comment: Smuxi, I'm not sure about URI integration, however there's certainly no DCC support. Pidgin has no URI integration either.

Comment: A better link for IRCII would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: @Oxwivi the official link for IRCII: [link](http://www.eterna.com.au/ircii/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will be light-weight enough for you but [Konversation](http://konversation.kde.org/) might fit the bill.

Comment: 309 MB more will be taken up if I want to install Konversation in LXDE...

Comment: I guess not then ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The X chat link indeed is very script orientated but the easy way is this X chat command

/set gui_url_mod = 0

Just make sure to shut down X chat normally and it will be remembered.

Comment: Looked this command up, it's for a completely different issue.

Answer (score 0):

The [Opera browser](http://www.opera.com/browser/features/) offers a built-in IRC client. No logging, though, which can be a turn-off.