# Open irc:// links in XChat from Firefox/Chrome on 11.10

Tags: 11.10, unity, firefox, irc, xchat

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open irc:// links in XChat from Firefox and Chromium](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55779/open-irc-links-in-xchat-from-firefox-and-chromium)

I tried following the tips here:
[Open irc:// links in XChat from Firefox and Chromium](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55779/open-irc-links-in-xchat-from-firefox-and-chromium)

but none of them worked on 11.10.

I want to be able to click irc:// links on a browser and launch Xchat with the server/channel specified in the link. Most of them just open Xchat but do not automatically connect. Is there a specific way to do it with 11.10?

I did the script one, the gconfig one... none of them worked.

I'm a beginner using Ubuntu and Linux, and am of course using Unity.