# How does firefox open irc:// links?

Tags: firefox, irc

If I click on a link in the form of **irc://irc.hackint.eu/#ubuntu** I get a popup asking me, If I want to open it with the webclient [Mibbit.com](https://client00.chat.mibbit.com/?url=irc%3A%2F%2Firc.hackint.eu%2F%23ubuntu)

This used to work a few years ago, but I get no connection ever since.

How do I add more webclients there?

I would like to have Kiwi IRC as default:

https://kiwiirc.com/client/irc.eu.hackint.org/ubuntu?nick=askubuntuuser

I want to understand how the configuration in Firefox works and which config duke is related, so I can file a request to the responsible developers to change this obsolete default behaviour.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open irc:// links in XChat from Firefox and Chromium](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55779/open-irc-links-in-xchat-from-firefox-and-chromium)

Comment: It is not a duplicate. That page does not explain, why there is **always** Mibbit as default in Firefox on Ubuntu and where this was defined as default

Comment: Maybe its better to use ChatZilla add-one in firefox, It's a client for IRC. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/chatzilla/

Comment: I know how to use lots of IRC clients. My question is about understanding, how this default link to Mibbit is implemented.

Comment: Your question is unclear. It sounds as if you want someone to explain the code used by firefox ? It can be done more then one way as the link I gave you shows. If the link is not a duplicate, please update your question and clarify what you are asking.

Comment: seems related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox-3.5/+bug/461383/comments/46 and https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=435687 You should file a bugreport against (probably) the firefox package.